# How do I dynamically allocate a struct but not it's attributes?

Tags: c, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm a programming noob. I want to allocate a struct but since the size of my attributes are already defined, how would I use malloc() in this case?

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct sc sc_t;

struct sc {

    // Attributes

};
```

I've looked at several different examples but I'm still unsure if these examples entirely apply to me. Can this be accomplished by `sc_t * sc_t_new = (sc_t *)malloc(sizeof(sc_t));`?

Comment: What are "attributes" of a struct?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which part of the examples do your doubts address? BTW: In C it is not recommended to cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: @KamilCuk its just the body of my struct. In my case, the attributes are several arrays that already have a defined size.

Comment: You mean the members of your struct?

Comment: This ALWAYS work: `mytype *myPtr; myPtr = malloc(sizeof *myPtr);`

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you! Sorry yes members lol whoops. And the examples that I've looked at allocate structs in many different ways syntax-wise so I'm just unsure what applies to me. I've never used malloc before so thats part of the confusion. Does the inline code I wrote above allocate memory for simply the struct and not it's members?

Comment: What would a struct be without its members? A struct contains the members and if you allocate memory for a struct, this includes all members. Do you mean extra memory for pointers?

Comment: Why do you think this would not work?

Comment: Please provide an example where you think it does not apply.

Comment: @klutt Thank you! So for me it would be something like `sc_t *sc_tPtr = malloc(sizeof *sc_tPtr);` correct?

Comment: @Lauren Yes that's correct

Comment: @Gerhardh For context, someone in my class asked the TA "Since the array attributes in our struct have a defined size and are not allocated on the heap, it's safe to only free the struct itself since it's the only thing allocated, correct?" and TA said that is correct. Like you said, I assumed allocating a struct allocated it's members as well so that's why the above context confused me. The members of the struct are mostly integer arrays with a macro size and I have to later populate the arrays with data from a csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question doesn't make sense. A struct is its members (what you called "attributes"). It's like asking how to make an omelette that doesn't contain eggs in a frying pan with no bottom on a stove with no burners.

More programming-related, it's like asking how to allocate an `int` without any digits.

You just allocate a struct and the struct has its members inside it already.

You can use:

```
sc_t * sc_t_new = malloc(sizeof(sc_t));
```

(the extra `(sc_t*)` is not needed in C, only in C++)

You can also use:

```
sc_t * sc_t_new = malloc(sizeof(*sc_t_new));
```

which helps prevent you from making a mistake if you decide to change it to a different struct later.

---

> For context to my nonsensical question, someone in my class asked the TA "Since the array attributes in our struct have a defined size and are not allocated on the heap, it's safe to only free the struct itself since it's the only thing allocated, correct?" and TA said that is correct.

Your classmate was probably confused about structs that contain pointers. If you have code like this:

```
struct S {
    int *a;
};

struct S *s = malloc(sizeof(struct S));
s->a = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
```

then the pointer variable `a` is a member of the struct, but the array of 100 ints is not - that is completely separate from the struct!

If you did this:

```
free(s);
```

it would free the struct, but not the array. To free the struct and the array you would do this:

```
free(s->a);
free(s);
```

Pay attention: *that's because the array is not a member in this case*. Only the *pointer* to the array is a member.

Comment: The first paragraph! :D

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Lol I do enjoy that analogy. For context to my nonsensical question, someone in my class asked the TA "Since the array attributes in our struct have a defined size and are not allocated on the heap, it's safe to only free the struct itself since it's the only thing allocated, correct?" and TA said that is correct. I assumed allocating a struct allocated it's members as well so that's why the above context confused me. The members of the struct are mostly integer arrays with a macro size and I have to later populate the arrays with data from a csv file.

Comment: @Lauren They were probably confused about structs that contain pointers. If you have something like `struct S {int *a;}; struct S *s = malloc(sizeof(struct S)); s->a = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);`, the pointer variable `a` is a member of the struct, but the array it points to is not - it's completely separate from the struct! I updated the answer with more information about this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 5

typedef struct {
    char name[100];
} e_struct;

int main(void) {
    // Allocating MAX_ELEMENTS number of elements of type 'e_struct'
    e_struct *n = (e_struct *)malloc(sizeof(e_struct) * MAX_ELEMENTS);

    // Some usage of *n then free the memory...
    free(n);

    return 0;
}
```

This line:

```
e_struct *n = (e_struct *)malloc(sizeof(e_struct) * MAX_ELEMENTS);
```

Will tell the compiler to allocate the memory for `n` pointer of type `e_struct` for `MAX_ELEMENT` bytes times the size of the `e_struct` in bytes (i.e. `MAX_ELEMENTS * sizeof(e_struct)`:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  ELEM1   |  ELEM2   |  ELEM3   |  ELEM4   |  ELEM5   |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|name[100] | name[100]| name[100]| name[100]| name[100]|
+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```